# novice needs process array in class more efficiently

Tags: php, arrays, class, process

Being new to PHP classes, I'm trying to find out the best way to retrieve values from textfiles (e-mail messages). The textfile is converted line by line into an array. I am processing multiple textfiles in one go. From some textfiles I need to retrieve more information than others, so I have created a class containing all the functions I need. This is (in short) what I have come up with:

```
<?php
$to_process = array(
    '9/24/15 11:03:04 PM    Task Start',
    '[...]',
    '[...]',
    '9/24/15 11:25:54 PM    Task Stop',
    '    ',
    '    '
    );

    $message = new process;

    $start  = $message->retrieve_start(to_process);
    $stop   = $message->retrieve_stop(to_process);

class process {

    function retrieve_start($arr) {
        $start = explode(" ", $arr[0]);
        return $this->$start[1];
    }

    function retrieve_other($arr) {
        // do stuff
    }

    function retrieve_stop($arr) {
        // do other stuff
    }

}
?>
```

It does the job, but everytime one of the functions is called, the array is passed to the function. That does not look very efficient to me. How can I make this more efficient?

Comment: Does the `$to_process` array change when you process different text files? Or is it always the same?

Comment: Each text file is a new array. I'm processing e-mail messages into our monitoring software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize a constructor method to load the process array into the object once like this

```
<?php
class process {

    protected $to_process = array();

    public function __construct($theProcessArray)
    {
        $this->to_process = $theProcessArray;
    }

    public function retrieve_start() 
    {
        $start = explode(" ", $this->to_process[0]);
        return $start[1];
    }

    public function retrieve_other() 
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    public function retrieve_stop() 
    {
        // do other stuff
    }
}

$to_process = array('9/24/15 11:03:04 PM    Task Start',
                    '[...]', '[...]',
                    '9/24/15 11:25:54 PM    Task Stop',
                    '    ', '    ');

$message = new process($to_process);

$start  = $message->retrieve_start($to_process);
$stop   = $message->retrieve_stop($to_process);
?>
```

Comment: I changed: $start  = $message->retrieve_start(to_process); to $start  = $message->retrieve_start() to get it working...

Comment: O yea, woops a typo, beg your pardon.